# End condition for precision integration loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to integrate the function 1/((1+x^2)x^0.5) using the trapezium rule. I need the precision to be as great as possible so I am therefore increasing the number of strips, N, until the computer cannot recognise a change between the total for consecutive N. However, the end condition is not currently working, leading to continuous integration. Does anyone have any better suggestions than my current code?

Many thanks,
Beth

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>

double inter(double x, double h, double y, double N, double total) 
{

        total= total +0.5*(1/((1+pow(x,2))*sqrt(x)));

        x=x+h;

        while (x<y)
        {
            total=total+(1/((1+pow(x,2))*sqrt(x)));

            x=x+h;

            //printf("x - %.16lf \n", x);
        }
        total= total +0.5*(1/((1+pow(x,2))*sqrt(x)));
    total=total*h;
    //printf("t - %lf \n", total);
    return total;
    }
main()

{   
double x,y,total,h,value,newvalue,f, N;
int finish;
x=0.1;
    y=1000;
    total=0;
    N=1000;
finish=0;
value=0;

while(finish==0)
{   
    h=(y-x)/(N-1); 

    newvalue=inter(x,h,y,N,total);
    printf("h-%.16lf\n", h);
    printf("N-%.16lf\n", N);
    printf("New value %.16lf\n", newvalue);
    printf("c-%.16lf\n", value);
    if(value==newvalue)
    {
        finish=1;   
        printf("finish-%d\n", finish);
    }
    else
        {
            value=newvalue;
            newvalue=newvalue-3;
            N=N+1000;
            printf("newvalue-%lf\n", newvalue);
            printf("value-%lf\n", value);
        }



}
printf("%lf\n", value);
}
```

Comment: Normally continuous integration is a good thing. ;)

Comment: Apart from being an update of your earlier question today, perhaps you might find this similar question helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018299/numerical-integration-using-the-trapezium-rule-in-c/29018405

Comment: What output do you get from the `printf`s? You might want to start with one `printf` that says `printf("old=%.16lf new=%.16lf diff=%.16le\n", value,newvalue,newvalue-value);`

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to create an automatic refinement of your numerical integration, one technique is to look at the relative convergence of your integration.

```
double previous = 0;
double current = inter( x, (y-x)/(N-1), y, N, total ); // Solve some baseline
do
{
    N = N + 1000;
    h = (y-x)/(N-1);
    previous = current;
    current = inter( x, h, y, N, total );
} while( abs( current - previous ) / current > 0.001 );
```

That code will stop after you observe less than 0.1% relative refinement in your estimation. Decreasing `0.001` will effectively increase your accuracy. Usually the best way to compare doubles is through a tolerance check like:

```
abs( a - b ) < k
```

where `k` is some factor of the order of accuracy you wish to achieve.

Comment: Your comments about comparing `double`s are misleading.  You certainly *can* check for exact equality of `double`s, and occasionally it's even the right thing to do.  Although you are right that it is much more often appropriate to test whether `double`s are closer than some threshold, a fixed multiple of `DBL_MIN` is typically not the right threshold because values exactly representable by type `double` are not equally dense across the range of representable values.  Better is some number of units in the last place of the target value's representation.

Comment: Noted. I agree I personally don't use DBL_MIN in my code but I thought it might be more formal too (maybe not ;) ).

Comment: Your revision improved your answer.  The key point is that tests for whether `double` values are approximately equal need to be relative to their observed or presumed magnitude, as you start off saying.  In particular, the test `abs(a - b) < k * DBL_MIN` that you originally proposed is not meaningfully different from `a == b` in most cases, even with rather large `k`.

Comment: Recommend `fabs()` rather than `abs()`

Answer (score 1):

This integral is difficult because the f(x) -> ∞ as x -> 0. In this example, I changed the range to 1 to 1000. I also used a summation function to minimize rounding error when summing up a large number of values. The integral from wolframalpha ~= .487474, this program results in ~=.487475 . The exact integral can be found using this link:

[integral 1/((1+x^2)sqrt(x))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28%281%2Bx%5E2%29*sqrt%28x%29%29)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>

/* clear array */
void clearsum(double asum[2048])
{
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        asum[i] = 0.;
}

/* add a number into array */
void addtosum(double d, double asum[2048])
{
size_t i;
    while(1){
        /* i = exponent of d */
        i = ((size_t)((*(unsigned long long *)&d)>>52))&0x7ff;
        if(i == 0x7ff){         /* max exponent, could be overflow */
            asum[i] += d;
            return;
        }
        if(asum[i] == 0.){      /* if empty slot store d */
            asum[i] = d;
            return;
        }
        d += asum[i];           /* else add slot to d, clear slot */
        asum[i] = 0.;           /* and continue until empty slot */
    }
}

/* return sum from array */
double returnsum(double asum[2048])
{
double sum = 0.;
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        sum += asum[i];
    return sum;
}

double fx(double x)
{
    return 1./((1.+x*x)*sqrt(x));
}

double inter(double x, double y, double n) 
{
double asum[2048];              /* for summation functions */
double h;
double d;
    if(n < 1.){
        n = 1.;
        h = 0.;
    } else {
        h = (y-x)/(n-1.0);
    }
    y -= h/2.;
    clearsum(asum);
    d = .5*h*fx(x);
    addtosum(d, asum);
    for( ; x < y; x += h){
        d = h*fx(x);
        addtosum(d, asum);
    }
    d = .5*h*fx(x);
    addtosum(d, asum);
    d = returnsum(asum);
    return d;
}

int main()
{   
double x,y,n,value,newvalue;
    x=1.0;
    y=1000.;
    value=0.;

    for(n = 100000000.; 1; n += 100000000.)
    {   
        newvalue=inter(x,y,n);
        printf("new value %.16lf %.0lf\n", newvalue, n);
        if(fabs(newvalue-value) < (newvalue*1E-7))
            break;
        value = newvalue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using Simpson's rule, the results are more accurate and converge at much smaller values for n:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>

/* clear array */
void clearsum(double asum[2048])
{
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        asum[i] = 0.;
}

/* add a number into array */
void addtosum(double d, double asum[2048])
{
size_t i;
    while(1){
        /* i = exponent of d */
        i = ((size_t)((*(unsigned long long *)&d)>>52))&0x7ff;
        if(i == 0x7ff){         /* max exponent, could be overflow */
            asum[i] += d;
            return;
        }
        if(asum[i] == 0.){      /* if empty slot store d */
            asum[i] = d;
            return;
        }
        d += asum[i];           /* else add slot to d, clear slot */
        asum[i] = 0.;           /* and continue until empty slot */
    }
}

/* return sum from array */
double returnsum(double asum[2048])
{
double sum = 0.;
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        sum += asum[i];
    return sum;
}

double fx(double x)
{
    return 1./((1.+x*x)*sqrt(x));
}

double simpson(double x, double y, double n) 
{
double asum[2048];              /* for summation functions */
double h;
double a;
    if(n < 1.){
        n = 1.;
        h = 0.;
    } else {
        h = (y-x)/(n-1.0);
    }
    y += h/2.;
    clearsum(asum);
    for( ; x < y; x += h){
        a = h/6.*(fx(x) + 4.*fx(x + h/2.) + fx(x + h));
        addtosum(a, asum);
    }
    a = returnsum(asum);
    return a;
}

int main()
{   
double x,y,n,value,newvalue;
    x=1.0;
    y=1000.;
    value=0.;

    for(n = 1000.; 1; n += 1000.)
    {   
        newvalue=simpson(x,y,n);
        printf("new value %.16lf %.0lf\n", newvalue, n);
        if(fabs(newvalue-value) < (newvalue*1E-10))
            break;
        value = newvalue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```